# Saving checkboxes in wordpress custom post type

Tags: checkbox, wordpress, custom-post-type

Hi I have checkboxes defined as such:

```
"languages" => array("name" => "languages",
"title" => "Languages","description" => "",
"style" => "checkboxes","options" => array("1" => "option1","2" => "option2")),
```

they display fine using:

```
foreach($meta_box['options'] as $radio_value) { 
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$meta_box['name'].'_value'.'"
value="'.$radio_value.'"'; if ($meta_box_value == $radio_value) { echo ' 
checked="yes"'; } echo '/> '.$radio_value. '<br/>';
```

Now I need to save them.

I am using this code to save all the other fields, but naturally it will only save the last checked checkbox:

```
if(get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value') == "")
   add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', $data, true);
elseif($data != get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true))
   update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', $data);
elseif($data == "")
  delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'].'_value', true));
```

How would i fix this to save all the checked checkboxes.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: this might be more suited for wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Here's a helpful link on creating meta boxes: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields/.

You might end up tossing what you currently have, but I employ this method on my own blogs and it works quite well.